# Contact permission sets with Platform license?

Tags: contact, permission-sets, licenses

I have the executive contact object created in staging sandbox.  The contact object is set to private.  I created a General Contacts permission set and assigned it to everyone to allow them to view 'Standard' contact record types, not 'Executive 'record types.  This works on all the salesforce licenses.  But the permission set doesn't work on the platform licenses.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does this permission set have any other feature? or access to any other internal object like order opportunity cases ?

Comment: Hey @PranayJaiswal it just grants access to the standard contact record type with nothing special on any other object.

Comment: When you have createc the permissionset have you associated it any license? or set it as None

Comment: We selected none at first and then changed it to associate it to the platform license